# Different Way for making Gradle Faster

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have been working on android from some time. Since starting i have searching ways of make the grade efficient and fast. i went through many post and i find many solution. which i am listing here.

1. After building first time switch to offline mode.
2. make parallel exception check in grade compiler option.
3. use Dexoption to increase the heap size.

I am looking for  if is any other thing which can help reducing the gradle time.

**A.** what are the other option which can be used in gradle to make is efficient and fast. ( i am looking for both gradle normal and experimental plugin - as dexoption are not available in experimental plugin)?

**B.** Is there any drawback of the instant run on the build time introduced in studio 2.0?

**C.** Which is the gradle plugin version best for android 2.0?

**D.** Any other thing which we can implement in code or in script to decrease the build time and run time?

Answer (score 1):

If you have:

- **Android Studio 2.0+**
- **Gradle 2.0+**
- minSDK **API 15** (Android 4.0) declaration in your app
- your device is API21+

then you should be able to use **Android Instant Run feature**.

---

As described [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/instant-run) app are building almost instantly in most cases. There are 3 running modes available: hot swap, warm swap and cold swap.
Building speed depends of code change scope.